# Ignoring hidden files with gulp-watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I am watching an entire folder for file modifications, I want to ignore some of the files. For example, I want to watch all files, but ignore those that start with a period (`.`). How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I would say something like this should work:

```
gulp.watch(['css/**/*', '!css/**/.*'], ['styles']);
```

Comment: I forgot about `"!**/*"` patterns. I will try it.